Why isn't the client receiving the data through the Socket.IO emit from the server?
I'm making a chat application with socket.io, the frontend is with react and the backend with express. I'm following the steps from the official documentation, but it is just getting even worse. From the frontend I can emit data, on the server I catch them, but it receives twice somehow. For example when I login, the log_in will catch the data from the frontend, but the data will be received two times added in the active users array, the frontend doesn't receive any data from the server when I emit it.
What should I change to get it to work?
Here is the frontend:
import { socket } from './helper/socket';

function App() {
  const { username } = useAppSelector(state => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    const refreshUsers = data => {
      console.log('App.tsx refresh users' + data);
    };
    const receiveMessage = data => {
      console.log('App.tsx receive message' + data);
    };
    socket.on('refresh_users', refreshUsers);
    socket.on('receive_message', receiveMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.off('refresh_users', refreshUsers);
      socket.off('receive_message', receiveMessage);
    };
  }, []);

  function NoMatch() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <h2>404: Page Not Found</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className='bg-gray-800 min-h-dvh flex justify-center flex-row mx-auto py-24 px-36'>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute user={username} redirectPath='/login' />}>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/sign-up' element={<Register />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
          <Route path='*' element={<NoMatch />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

socket.ts:
import io, { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
export const socket: Socket = io(import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URI);

backend app.js file:
const app = express();
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: 'http://localhost:5173/' } });
const sqlite = sqlite3.verbose();
let sql;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

//routes
app.use('/api/users', userRoute);
app.use('/api/message', authenticateToken, messageRoute);

let activeUsers = [];

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('connected: ' + socket.id);
  socket.on('log_in', data => {
    activeUsers.push({ username: data, userId: socket.id });
    refreshActiveUsers();
    console.log(activeUsers);
  });

  const refreshActiveUsers = () => {
    console.log(activeUsers);
    socket.emit('refresh_users', activeUsers);
  };

  socket.on('send_message', async data => {
    console.log(data);
    io.emit('receive_message', data);
  });
  socket.on('clickedOnUser', data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`user ${socket.id} disconnected`);
    activeUsers = activeUsers.filter(user => user.userId !== socket.id);
    refreshActiveUsers();
    console.log(activeUsers);
  });
});

At some point it worked, but I change the code because it was more than once connected on the frontend, so I went back to the official docs and made a custom file for the socket as it is written in the docs.
Probably the problem is on the frontend side, the useEffect doesn't have any dependency, but neither have the official docs.
https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react
